# jQuery slide down panel

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

its my first time using .animate() from jQuery. My main idea is panel with picture will appear within 2 seconds, and sliding down. But currently its not working, can you make it work?

You can see demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/8WN5c/3/

If you can't see it, here is copied version.

HTML:

```
<div id="panel">
    <img src="http://fusedfilm.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/spider-man.jpg" alt="dummy image" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#panel {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; 
    height: 0px; 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#panel").animate({
    height: 320,
    overflow: visible
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you meant something more like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8WN5c/6/

This will actually slide the image down into place by moving the relative position of the image.

The "panel" in this case acts like a picture frame. The image can't be seen when it's outside the frame, and the image slides down into the frame.

HTML:

```
<div id="panel">
        <div id="slideDownPanel">
    <img src="http://fusedfilm.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/spider-man.jpg" alt="dummy image" />
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {background-color: #000}
#panel {
    width: 430px;
    height: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; 
}
#slideDownPanel
{
    width: 430px;
    height: 320px;
    position: relative;
    top: -320px;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#slideDownPanel").animate({
    top: 0
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Many times thanks, It now working perfect. Thanks for shifting top value trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/8WN5c/5/

How `overflow: visible` is supposed to be animated?

Comment: I added it because <div> has <img> and no matter div's height value, image showing full. Btw its working as I expected thanks.

Answer (score 1):

new to jsfiddle.. but this works.
You need to either make a frame around what you are moving to reference it or move the object itself and keep the frame still.

```
     _______________
    |               |     
    |               |     
---------------------------
|   |               |     |
|   |               |     |
|   |sliding image  |     |
|   |---------------|     |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
| viewport                |
---------------------------
```

**normal view**
http://jsfiddle.net/8WN5c/9/ 
**The single screen view**.
http://jsfiddle.net/8WN5c/9/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

js for your example

```
$("#panel").animate({

    height: 320,

}, 2000);
```

and css for your example

```
body {background-color: #000}
#panel {
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 0px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```